# Updating values of a temp table based on values from another Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
declare @company_branch_id  uniqueidentifier = 'd3534ff2-b2b2-473f-9be1-e03069bf5c87'
declare @dateFrom date = '10/8/2013'
declare @dateTo date = '11/9/2013'


DECLARE @tbl    TABLE(
    tbl_Ref varchar(50)
    , Reference varchar(100)
    , customer_branch_id uniqueidentifier
    , trans_date datetime
    , duedate datetime
    , Charge decimal(18,4)
    , Credits decimal(18,4)
    , Allocated decimal(18,4)
    , Outstanding decimal(18,4)
    , pay_amount decimal(18,4))

Insert into @tbl
Exec [dbo].[usp_getCustomerBalanceRpt] @company_branch_id, @dateFrom, @dateTo

UPDATE @tbl
SET trans_date = (SELECT tbl_Rental_InvoiceMaster.Date 
                  FROM tbl_Rental_InvoiceMaster
                  INNER JOIN @tbl ON @tbl.Reference = tbl_Rental_InvoiceMaster.Reference
                  WHERE tbl_Rental_InvoiceMaster.Reference= @tbl.Reference
                  AND @tbl.tbl_Ref='Rental Invoice')
SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

@company_branch_id, @dateFrom, @dateTo are the arguments passed to the sp.
While executing the above code ERROR is displayed near

```
INNER JOIN @tbl ON @tbl.Reference = tbl_Rental_InvoiceMaster.Reference
WHERE tbl_Rental_InvoiceMaster.Reference= @tbl.Reference
AND @tbl.tbl_Ref='Rental Invoice'
```

as `'Must declare the scalar variable "@tbl".'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use a table variable in a join, we need to alias the table in order to execute the query.

Following query should work:

```
UPDATE @tbl
SET trans_date = (SELECT tbl_Rental_InvoiceMaster.Date 
                  FROM tbl_Rental_InvoiceMaster
                  INNER JOIN @tbl t ON t.Reference = tbl_Rental_InvoiceMaster.Reference
                  WHERE tbl_Rental_InvoiceMaster.Reference= t.Reference
                  AND t.tbl_Ref='Rental Invoice')
SELECT * FROM @tbl
```